# Unavailable configurable swatches on product page showing available on load until mouseover

Tags: configurable-product, product-page, configurable-swatches

I have searched high and low to try and answer this one but to no avail thus far.

I have show out of stock products turned on through Magento 1.9.3.7 which is all working fine however on product page load all options show as if they are available until the mouse enters the swatch area and then the unavailable ones are then grayed out.

How can I get the unavailable swatches to show grey on page load.

I hope the above makes sense and an example can be seen at http://ooooosh.com/pleaser-adore-7802 for further clarity.

I thank you so much in advance as this is driving me insane! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find `var swatchesConfig` declared in `template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml`.

On the latest Magento 1.9.4.5 it should be declared in `template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/configurable/swatch-js.phtml`

Also, in `js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js` is a method called `setAvailableOptions`, so you can call that method in `swatches.phtml`:

```
    var swatchesConfig = new Product.ConfigurableSwatches(spConfig);
    swatchesConfig.setAvailableOptions();
```